# ¿Como se mueve un elemento en una ventana dependiendo de su tamaño?

Tags: html, css

Tengo un logo que me ocupa una tercera parte de la pantalla, pero que se redimensiona al cambiar el tamaño de la pantalla verticalmente, el logo tiene forma de triángulo. Mi menú debe quedar en la punta de ese triángulo, ¿como hago para que ese menú se mantenga en la punta de mi triángulo al redimensionar la pantalla?

Edit: Comparto mi código y una imagen de como se ve ahora y como debe quedar. Tiene unas animaciones que se activan en la primera carga de la página, pero eso no debería afectar al menú.

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <title>BOOM Design</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <figure class="bottom-triangle">
                <img src="img/triangle1.svg" alt="">
            </figure>
            <figure class="top-triangle">
                <img src="img/triangle2.svg" alt="">
            </figure>
          <figure class="boomlogo">
              <img src="img/logo.svg" alt="">
          </figure>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
    html, body{
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .container{
      background-image: url(../img/background1.jpg);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      opacity: 1;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      position: relative;
      -webkit-animation-name: opening;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
      animation-name: opening;
      animation-duration: 1s;
      z-index: 0;
    }

    /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    @-webkit-keyframes opening {
      from {opacity: 0;}
      to {opacity: 1;}
    }

    /* Standard syntax */
    @keyframes opening {
      from {opacity: 0;}
      to {opacity: 1;}
    }

    .bottom-triangle {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      -webkit-animation-name: entering; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
      animation-name: entering;
      animation-duration: 1s;
      z-index: 2;
    }

    .top-triangle {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      -webkit-animation-name: entering2; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
      animation-name: entering2;
      animation-duration: 1.5s;
      z-index: 3;
    }

    .boomlogo {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 1;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      -webkit-animation-name: entering3; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
      -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
      animation-name: entering3;
      animation-duration: 2s;
      z-index: 4;
    }


    /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    @-webkit-keyframes entering {
      from {left: -445px;}
      to {left: 0;}
    }

    /* Standard syntax */
    @keyframes entering {
      from {left: -445px;}
      to {left: 0;}
    }

    /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    @-webkit-keyframes entering2 {
      from {left: -900px;}
      to {left: 0;}
    }

    /* Standard syntax */
    @keyframes entering2 {
      from {left: -900px;}
      to {left: 0;}
    }

    /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    @-webkit-keyframes entering3 {
      from {opacity: 0;}
      to {opacity: 1;}
    }

    /* Standard syntax */
    @keyframes entering3 {
      from {opacity: 0;}
      to {opacity: 1;}
    }

    .container figure img {
      height: 100vh;
    }
```

Así está ahora

[image: Así está ahora]

Así debe quedar

[image: Así debe quedar]

Comment: Sin tu código **HTML** y **CSS** es difícil ayudarte. ¿Podrías facilitarlo? Una imagen del resultado obtenido y del deseado ayudaría también. Este sitio Web cuenta con una herramienta para insertar código y que todos podamos ejecutarlo desde aquí, (accesible desde dentro del editor de texto que se te abre cuando creas una nueva pregunta o respuesta) montar tu código con esta herramienta ayudaría a que las posibles respuestas que te lleguen sean más fieles a tu problema y más satisfactorias.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender cómo funciona el sitio y ganar tu primera medalla. También a que edites tu pregunta y añadas un [mcve], de esa forma quienes tengan la buena intención de ayudarte puedan darte una solución que se adapte a lo que ya llevas desarrollado.

Comment: Ok, editada la publicación para explicar mejor que es lo que quiero hacer. ¡Gracias por ayudar!